# Layering divs on top of other divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple page 2 divs that are full screen that act as the background colours. Then I was 2 smaller divs layered on top of these background divs that I can put words in with a button underneath that to randomise the words. (screenshot attached with what I want to achieve).

[Screenshot of Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af032.png)

I have this code currently for the background divs but I can seem to get anything to layer on top of those...

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner.left {
  background-color: brown;
}

.inner.right {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner left"></div>
  <div class="inner right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please always show what you tried, even if it wasn’t successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u expecting like this:

```css
body,html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.one{
width:50%;
background-color:brown;
float:left;
margin:auto;
height:100vh;
}
.inner_1{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right:50%;
  width:200px;
  line-height:60px;
  background-color:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.inner_2{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background-color:#7be0ff;
  width:200px;
  line-height:60px;
  text-align:center;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.two{
width:50%;
background-color:#bebebe;
float:left;
height:100vh;
}
.button{
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top:70%;
 background-color: #6afa70; /* Green */
 left: 50%;
 -ms-transform: translate( -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%);
 border:none;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="one">
<div class="inner_1">Div layer on top 1</div>
</div>
<div class="two">
<div class="inner_2">Div layer on top 2</div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="button" value=" Button">
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about vertically aligning the content `div`'s? If so, using `table-cell` and `float`s, you could do something like this:

```css
.container{ 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
 }
.inner{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.inner.left{
    background-color: brown;
}
.inner.right{
    background-color: grey;
}
.inner-sub{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.inner-sub .align{
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner-sub .align .content{
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    float: right;
}
.right .inner-sub .align .content{
    float: left;
}
.button-container button{
    position: absolute;
    right: -28px; /* half of the width of the button */
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 70px; /* set this depending on how far away you want the button to be from the elements */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner left">
        <div class="inner-sub">
            <div class="align button-container">
                <div class="content">div layed on top 1</div>
                <button>Button</button>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner right">
        <div class="inner-sub">
            <div class="align">
                <div class="content">div layed on top 2</div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nvL6wyoj/2/

Comment: Yes this is pretty much exactly what i am looking for!! How would I get the 2 smaller divs to be edge to edge like in the screenshot I uploaded?

Comment: @Miles.Kelly they should be touching anyway :) the iFrame for this snippet is just glitchy I think ha. I've updated the JsFiddle to be correctly displayed to show how it should look!:)

Comment: Ahh that's wicked! Thank you. In terms of getting a button/another elemenrt to sit centre aligned over the twio background divs how would I achieve this?

Comment: @Miles.Kelly what I would do is add the button into the left `align` div and then add a `margin-right` with a negative value of the width of the button itself. I'll update for you :)